# onChange on MUI Select is returning the previous value instead of the current

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, web, react-hooks

I have the following code using React Hooks and MUI Select component.

```
<Select variant='outlined' 
        value={plan} 
        onChange={setPlanAndAmount} 
        style={{ width: '98%' }} >
  <MenuItem value={'bronze'} >Bronze</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={'silver'} >
    Silver
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={'gold'} >
    Gold
  </MenuItem>
</Select>
```

The `onChange` handler is:

```
 const setPlanAndAmount = (e) => {
   setPlan(e.target.value)

   switch(plan) {
       case 'bronze':
         setGiftingAmount('99.99')
         break;
       case 'silver':
         setGiftingAmount('199.99')
         break;
       case 'gold':
         setGiftingAmount('299.99')
         break;
       default:
         setGiftingAmount('99.99')
         break;         
       }
  }
```

What is does is that it takes the plan, runs it through a SWITCH statement and sets the giftingAmount which is used elsewhere.
What the problem is the first time I select a plan, nothing happens but the next time I'm doing it  it returns the previous value instead on the current one.

What's the solution for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the updater provided by `useState` is asynchronous, since state values relies on closure and changes on next re-render. Check this for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/9119053

You can try doing this:

```
 const setPlanAndAmount = (e) =>{
const updatedPlan = e.target.value;
        setPlan(updatedPlan)

        switch(updatedPlan){
            case 'bronze':
                setGiftingAmount('99.99')
                break;
            case 'silver':
                setGiftingAmount('199.99')
                break;
            case 'gold':
                setGiftingAmount('299.99')
                break;
            default:
                setGiftingAmount('99.99')
                break;         
        }
    }
```

Or use `useEffect` to update `giftingAmount`